# Tag [naming] is too broad and has no value in identifying questions

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

There is a tag [naming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/naming) with the following text:

> A general purpose tag to cover anything concerning naming, be it files, programming constructs, data etc.

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/naming/info

Usage of the tag is not really clear, and the tag does not really help identifying relevant questions. The signal-to-noise ratio is quite low. It does not add meaningful information to posts.

I can imagine that tags like [naming-conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/naming-conventions) or [naming-constrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/naming-constrictions) or even [azure-resource-naming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-resource-naming) would be better suited to distinguish questions and attract the right attention.

Votes on questions with the tag [naming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/naming) are a bit of a red herring, as most questions with this tag have multiple other tags as well. The value of the tag [naming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/naming) itself lost on me.

Can we improve the usage of this tag?

Comment: Seems like one of those handy tags like "if-statement" to throw on your ignored tags list to instantly weed out a bunch of garbage.

Comment: I actually like that tag, good naming is a very big deal.  So do 3 experts that have a significant number of votes in the tag: Jon Skeet, VonC and Ben Smith.  And 28 users that subscribed it.  Answer rates are normal, voting is healthy.  Maybe aim a bit lower?  Surely you then hate [naming-conventions] and [conventions] too.  At least removing those doesn't re-activate so many questions.

Comment: @HansPassant what makes you think i "hate" this or other tags? Please keep this discussion on track and avoid personal statements here.

Comment: Well, appreciated from your end as well, thanks in advancement.  I really do like the tag btw, I can't unlike it.  The opposite of love is not hate, it is indifference.  Almost nobody ever "defends" a tag, crappy job.

Comment: Experts are people who answer lots of questions, therefore it is only natural that three top users have votes in `[naming]`, since each question has multiple tags. And isn't naming often a very opinion-based matter, especially outside the scope of naming conventions?

Comment: [naming] is hard.

Comment: @hanspassant could you post an answer here with reasons for letting the tag stay?

Comment: It would be good to provide some example usages. A quick glance suggests that for most of the questions in this tag, actually coming up with a good name for anything (which is what the tag wiki suggests is its intended purpose) has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @HansPassant I think the reason there's very little defense of tags is that most of the ones that come on Meta serve little purpose and probably hurt more than they help. If someone suggested burning [tag:C++], obviously there would be vigorous defense and attempts to help the asker become less confused. I suspect most questions about how to name something would be off topic as they'd be more about English than about software. The only kind I can think of that might be on topic is asking about being consistent with some jargon from existing software, but even that feels iffy.

Comment: what is a good way to collect data on tag usage? (I know there are some api's on stackoverflow but have never used them).

Comment: I just mean scanning questions in the tag and picking out some demonstrative examples and summarizing how they use the tag (as in what they appear to assume the tag actually means). You literally just need to go to the tag page and look at some questions. That is usually enough to reveal if a tag is used halfway consistently or not.

Comment: I'm surprised there aren't more questions in this tag, considering that [naming is one of the two hard questions of computer science](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html). In all seriousness though, I agree that good naming is important, and `[naming]` is not a good name for a tag. Your suggestions of meaningful tag names, like `[naming-conventions]` is an example of a good name.

Comment: @RToyo After thinking about it, this situation is *sooo meta*.

Answer (score 3):

> Can we improve the usage of this tag?

There is limited opportunity for *improving* the usage of this tag. What needs to happen is a retag effort for questions that are otherwise on-topic and then the burnination of this tag.

The most common type of naming questions, such as "what should I name this variable" or "what are the naming conventions for this kind of thing" are **off-topic** on Stack Overflow as they are not only opinion-based questions, but questions about word choice, not programming.

Other questions, such as why you can't use a specific word for some method or variable may be better off with a different tag (such as [reserved-words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reserved-words)).